# Text color in Android device with API lower than 23 are not appearing correct?

Tags: android

I have made a app with its text color Blue but when I test it on a device with Android 5.1.0, API 22 or lower text color appears to be Black on device. But it work fine with android device with Android 6.0.0, API 23. Also I want to mention that rest of text formatting like font style are working fine.

Comment: can you please show us your code. XML or Screenshots for reference?

Comment: Please post the detail so we can help.

Comment: First of all i want to mention that as far as code is concerned everything seem to be fine. Also i don't find a way to provide code or screenshot in comment. I personally thing that there might be problem with Android Studio because many people are facing problem with font color. For now i will use setTextColor() method to set text. you can suggest me any general steps which i can try.

Answer (score 0):

Check your style.xml under res folder. There may be have style.xml in values-v23.

Comment: I checked my style.xml it is fine. I can't get what you are trying to say "There may be have style.xml in values-v23".

Comment: By mistakenly for text color code you may write in values-23=>style.xml. Must check it is in values=>style.xml